# Running docker daemon in i3

Tags: 22.04, docker, i3-wm

I recently switched from GNOME to i3 on my Ubuntu 22.04. I am having trouble running docker as a non-root user. If I run a docker command as-is, it'll give me a "Cannot connect error".

```
$> docker container ls
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/adarsh/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

The interesting thing is that in GNOME if I go and launch Docker Desktop from the applications, then I can use the docker commands without prepending `sudo`. But in `i3`, selecting the `docker-credential-desktop` from `rofi` does not launch anything, and I cannot run any docker commands as a non-root user.

If I try using `systemctl` to start `docker-desktop` as given in [Installation for Arch Linux](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/archlinux/), then it also fails

```
$> sudo systemctl start docker-desktop
Failed to start docker-desktop.service: Unit docker-desktop.service not found.
```

Just starting the docker service by `sudo service docker start` or `sudo systemctl start docker` works, but the problem persists.

Then I tried to start the daemon with `dockerd` as given in [Starting the docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/start/), but that also failed.

```
$> sudo dockerd
INFO[2024-02-07T15:45:41.739733781+05:30] Starting up                                  
failed to start daemon, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid: process with PID 11345 is still running

$> sudo rm /var/run/docker.pid
$> sudo dockerd
INFO[2024-02-07T15:46:07.461907886+05:30] Starting up                                  
failed to start daemon: error while opening volume store metadata database (/var/lib/docker/volumes/metadata.db): timeout
```

I have also followed all the instructions for [Post-installation in Linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) but it is still not running.

Note that with `sudo` it will run fine, but I want to run `docker` as non-root. It would be anyone could help me or point me in the right direction.

Comment: You are confusing .docker/desktop and normal `systemctl start docker`. See the "Important" warning box at the top of https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/